# list all beacons nearby you

Tags: swift, beacon

I am using below code to connect to my beacon.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        print("viewDidLoad==ViewController")

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("didChangeAuthorization")
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print("didRangeBeacons===\(beacons.count)")
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            print("basss---\(beacons[0].proximityUUID)")
            updateDistance(beacons[0].proximity)
        } else {
            updateDistance(.unknown)
        }
    }

    func updateDistance(_ distance: CLProximity) {
        print("updateDistance")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8) {
            switch distance {
            case .unknown:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

            case .far:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            case .near:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

            case .immediate:
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }


    func startScanning() {
        // 39316, 54420, 5268
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "86477363-EAB1-4988-AA99-B5C1517008D9")!
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 1, minor: 52681, identifier: "MyBeacon")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

This is working code.

However I want to list all nearby beacons.

Any idea how to do this?

---

The problem in current is I am telling which beacon to search in `startScanning`.

What I want to do is search all beacons which are there in range and display them.

Comment: You say the code works. If that's the case, have a look at your `didRangeBeacons` method. You could add a `var myBeacons: CLBeacon = []` in your view controller properties and update the beacon list whenever that fires.

Comment: @Adrian : If you see `startScanning`, I am passing uuid and minor/ major values which I don't want to.. I just want to list all nearby beacons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your region definition to not specify major or minor:

```swift
let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid,  identifier: "MyBeacon")
```

This will then match all beacons with that UUID regardless of major and minor.

If you want to match more UUIDs, you can construct up to 20 different regions, each with a different UUID and monitor and range on all of them.  (Be sure to change your identifier parameter for each region, too.)

However, there is a limit on the number of regions you can monitor (The 21st region registered for monitoring  will have no effect.). There is no hard limit on the number of regions you can range, but once you get beyond 100 or so, your app performance will reduce significantly.

Unfortunately, it is not possible on iOS to set up a region that matches all beacons regardless of UUID.  This is an Apple security restriction by design, albeit a silly one IMO.  Android, MacOS, Linux and Windows have no such restriction.